# How can I prevent systemctl reboot or systemctl poweroff from executing?

Tags: systemd

I work a lot SSHed into little SBCs and very often run `sudo systemctl reboot` or `sudo systemctl poweroff`

Every so often my SSH session had disconnected without me noticing, and I accidentally reboot my own machine. Is there any way to prevent reboot and poweroff from running, or even better to force me to type yes when I issue those commands?

I know I could alias those commands and retrain my brain to stop typing those commands, but that's not ideal. Also I'd still like to be able to run the rest of systemctl's commands via sudo, so I'd rather not block the whole of systemctl from running under sudo.

Comment: Once upon a time, the `shutdown -fr now` command have some protection against unwanted reboots(On Debian based systems, the `molly-guard` feature). It asked to type the hostname to complete this action. Could you please test if this behavior is available on your Linux with `systemd` ?

Comment: you could write a script calling these and asking confirmation

Comment: Not even a script is needed, but an alias would be enough. Examples here: http://www.redpill-linpro.com/sysadvent//2015/12/19/molly-guard.html

Comment: shutdown, reboot etc. are symlinked to systemctl on my system. I know I could write a script and alias for those commands, but the point is that I'm already so used to typing `sudo systemctl reboot` and so I was hoping to add something to the existing command, not replace it with another.

Comment: You could create another local user, with no sudo privileges, and run `ssh` as them (after copying the relevant ssh key, if necessary).  Then when the SSH session disconnects, typing commands into the resulting local shell will give you the "not in sudoers" warning instead.

Comment: Also, to make an accidental disconnection more unlikely I recommend [using **mosh**](https://mosh.org/)

Comment: https://www.2daygeek.com/how-to-avoid-or-prevent-accidental-shutdown-or-reboot-on-linux/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`reboot-guard`](https://github.com/ryran/reboot-guard) to protect against accidental reboots of your workstation. Example:

Activate at some point in time before you start working on your SBC:

```
# rguard -1
```

This blocks all kinds of reboots, e.g. `shutdown -r now`, a reboot triggered from graphical desktop environment, etc.

When you really want to reboot you can release the lock like this:

```
# rguard -0
```

Rguard also has some advanced options, i.e. for more dynamic and automatic activation/deactivation depending on external circumstances. But the basic functionality should be sufficient for many use cases.

(Tested it under Fedora 27.)

Comment: This looks cool. In your test you didn't notice the X session quitting when rguard is enabled? what version of systemd does Fedora 27 run?

Comment: @crazystick Fedora 27 currently has systemd 234. I tested ut in a root shell, inside a Tilix terminal, inside a graphical LXQt session. My graphical session wasn't terminated when testing the various shutdown commands/actions while rguard being active.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I'm surprised it's working for you. In my testing (tonight) the method reboot-guard employs causes fedora27's systemd-logind to crash ... every single time (and I tried multiple different systems). I filed a bug about it, though I don't have much confidence it will be dealt with swiftly. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1543720.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, because I'm sure this will be the solution when the bug in systemd is fixed. I'll come back and change that in case they decide that its no longer valid, but this would be so useful, why would they

Comment: @rsaw I tested that F27 system again - this time with `journalctl -f` running in another terminal. Yes, `rguard -1` works as expected for me: reboots are reliably prevented. Also: issuing a reboot/shutdown via the LXQt menu **does** yield a coredump in systemd-logind. But this doesn't terminate my LXQt session. lxqt-leave just briefly notifies: power manager error (D-BUS call) Message recipient disconnect from message bus without replying. FWIW, my LXQt session seems to run under Xorg (i.e. not wayland). A `shutdown -r/-h` from the terminal is blocked fine without systemd-logind coredumping.